# Gmail spam filtering issue

Tags: email, gmail

I am having problems getting emails delivered to Gmail inboxes.

I have properly set IP addresses with correct rDNS, SPF and DKIM settings. But whatever I do, I am unable to send emails to Gmail inbox. If I send an email with no link/image inside (HTML or text), it ends in Gmail inbox. But if I include a link to my website, then it ends in Spam folder.

Does Gmail have a domain black list? Does anyone have any suggestions?

IP, rDNS, SPF, DKIM everything is set properly. I even purchased a brand new dedicated server from SoftLayer to test it but still same results.

Comment: Your website link must be classified as spam by Google. Or you have malware on your website you may not be aware of.

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.iwebtool.com/google_banned will help?

Comment: I guess so. Our domain(s) might have been banned. But what to do? Is there any place to check for Gmail black list?

Comment: Vick, thanks for your comment but that service doesn't display any alerts.

Comment: In order to better troubleshoot, we may need more information: 1) Is this happening for specific messages or any messages you're sending to gmail? 2) Have you checked to see if you're listed on any other DNS blacklists? You can check here: http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx 3) Are you sending a lot of messages at once when this happens? For example, blasting out newsletters/notifications? 4) What format is the message that's getting quarantined (plain-text? rich-text? HTML?). 5) Are there any attachments with these messages? 6) When sending to gmail, are you getting any temporary errors?

Answer (score 1):

For google bulk sending help, you would need to contact google via https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126